# Kotlin extension field set/get with an exception

Tags: kotlin

I have defined a kotlin extension like this:

```
private var View.v: Boolean
    get() = this.visibility == View.VISIBLE
    set(visible) {
        if (visible) {
            this.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            this.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

However, there is some error when I try to use this field.

```
private var Int.v: Boolean
    get() = find<View>(this).v
    set(visible) = find<View>(this).v(visible)
```

The exception is:

```
Error:(40, 35) Expression 'v' of type 'Boolean' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is not the function. It is an extension property.

Do this instead:

```
private var Int.v: Boolean
   get() = find<View>(this).v
   set(visible) {
     find<View>(this).v = visible 
   }
```

Why would you create an extension property on view id? I think this is not the best idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I create an extension on R.id because I want to use the resource id like this `R.id.button.v = false` to hide the button.